# Constrain a type family constraint to be "some pair"

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families

Consider the following, where I'm trying to say "`a` is a pair":

```
type family F t a :: Constraint
type instance F Int a = (a ~ (a1, a2))
```

This doesn't work because both `a1` and `a2` are not in scope, but is there any way to express this?

Of course in a function signature I can write constraints like `(a ~ (a1, a2))` even when `a1` and `a2` are not mentioned elsewhere, but I need to put this in an instance function signature, which is of course determined by the class. And `a` in this case is not a parameter to the instance itself, just the instance function, much like `Functor` only has `f` as a class parameter, not `a` and `b`, so I can't add extra constraints to the instance clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! You can do this!

#### Strong, somewhat built-up version

First, a couple of useful type families:

```
type family Fst a where
  Fst (x,y) = x

type family Snd a where
  Snd (x,y) = y
```

Now the one you're after:

```
type IsPair a = a ~ (Fst a, Snd a)
```

Here's a test:

```
type family Con a where
  Con (f x y) = f

test :: IsPair a => proxy a -> Con a :~: (,)
test _ = Refl
```

And an even simpler one that turns out to test a stronger property:

```
 test1 :: IsPair a => a -> Fst a
 test1 = fst
```

And just to make sure it's satisfied when it should be:

```
data Dict c where
  Dict :: c => Dict c

test2 :: Dict (IsPair (a, b))
test2 = Dict
```

You can, of course, use this to define your `F`:

```
type family F t a
type instance F Int a = IsPair a
```

#### Much simpler, but much less powerful

```
type family Con a where
  Con (f x y) = f
type IsPair a = Con a ~ (,)
```

The trouble with this one, compared to the first approach, is that it doesn't actually win you the glorious knowledge that `a ~ (Fst a, Snd a)`. So it makes a statement, but you can't do a whole heck of a lot with it.

#### A little generalization

Why just pairs? If you toss `PolyKinds` into the mix, you can get very general:

```
type family Arg1 a where Arg1 (f x) = x
type family Arg2 a where Arg2 (f y x) = y
type family Arg3 a where Arg3 (f z y x) = z
type family Arg4 a where Arg4 (f w z y x) = w

type family IsF (f :: k) (a :: *) :: Constraint
type instance IsF f a = a ~ f (Arg1 a)
type instance IsF f a = a ~ f (Arg2 a) (Arg1 a)
type instance IsF f a = a ~ f (Arg3 a) (Arg2 a) (Arg1 a)
type instance IsF f a = a ~ f (Arg4 a) (Arg3 a) (Arg2 a) (Arg1 a)
```

You can do this without `PolyKinds` too, but then you need `IsF1`, `IsF2`, etc.

With this in place,

```
type IsPair a = IsF (,) a
type IsMaybe a = IsF Maybe a
...
```

Tests for the generalization (this stuff only works for GHC 7.10 or later; polykinds is too flaky before that).

```
data Dict c where
  Dict :: c => Dict c

test1 :: Dict (IsF f (f a))
test1 = Dict

test2 :: Dict (IsF f (f a b))
test2 = Dict

test3 :: Dict (IsF f (f a b c))
test3 = Dict

test4 :: Dict (IsF f (f a b c d))
test4 = Dict
```

Comment: You can even write it [once and for all](http://lpaste.net/7701963482375127040) for every arity with GHC 8.

Comment: @user2407038, cool! Your `Arg` is very clearly superior to my multiple `Arg` families. I haven't dug into the rest yet. One thing I couldn't find a way to do was work with kinds other than `*`. Does your approach do so?

Comment: @user2407038, does your thing allow `IsF (Either x) a`? It smells like it might not. Also, can you avoid the kind signatures in the tests using a kind class?

Comment: One more thing: would `Arg` be one of those rare cases where typelits would actually work well? That would make for a better API.

Comment: It happily works with kinds other than `*`, unless you mean the `Arg` family by itself, in which case, yes, it is written that way - a more powerful `Arg` is [possible](http://lpaste.net/5977620583607697408) but unnecessary here. [Here](http://lpaste.net/8258114670070595584) is a version in which `IsF (Either x) a` will also work - it is actually even simpler than the other one. I'm pretty sure you still can't do induction with type lits, so no, except for the syntactic convenience of writing e.g. `Arg .. 3` but for this you only need a `TypeLits.Nat -> Nat` type function.

Comment: @user2407038, I finally dug into your simplified code some more and figured out most of the answers to my initial "Why is it like that?" questions. That's a really nifty design that seems to be up to pretty much anything one could want from such.